# Rough path expected signature vs cumulant-generating function / characteristic function

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, rough-paths

What is the point of using rough path expected signature to characterize the law of а stochastic process when the cumulant generating function is known ($\log\mathbb{E}[e^{i\theta X(t)}]$)?

Since an average of group-like elements is not a group-like element, an expected signature (of a sample of paths) is not a signature, which seems to imply that expected signatures do not enjoy a nice geometric interpretation as signatures do. It seems that two main applications of expected signatures are the characterization of the law of a process (if moments completely describe the distribution) and the approximation of continuous functions on a collection of paths as linear functions on the expected signature of that collection of paths. If one doesn't need the latter use case, how is the description of a stochastic processes in terms of expected signatures qualitatively different from the classic characteristic function description? Is there something else that expected signatures can tell besides the moments?

For example, in case of Levy processes, characteristic function of a process has some very useful information about the process besides moments in light of Levy–Khintchine representation. It tells what parts this Levy process is composed of, namely its linear drift, Brownian motion, and Lévy jump process.

By expected signature I mean
$ \Big( \mathbb{E} \Big[ \int dX^{\otimes n} \Big]  \Big)_{n\geq 0} = \Big( \mathbb{E} \Big[\int_0^T \int_0^{r_n} \cdots \int_0^{r_2} dX_{r_1} \otimes \cdots  \otimes dX_{r_n} \Big]\Big)_{n\geq 0} $ described in [[LM22]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.14674.pdf) (Chapters 6 and 13), [[CO22]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.10971.pdf), [[LSDBL21]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.05805.pdf), [[BDMN20]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.13034.pdf).